# Which file of those files install a Joomla templates?

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to install new free Joomla template called [gk_magazine](https://www.gavick.com/download/joomla-themes/magazine). In the download page, I found three links to three zip files for **Joomla 3.x**:

- gk_magazine_rest_files_J!3.zip
- gk_magazine_quickstart_J!3.zip
- gk_magazine_J!3.zip

I downloaded the three files to my computer and I tried to install them one by one in the following order:

1. gk_magazine_J!3.zip: it is installed correctly and Gk_magazine template becomes listed in the template manager and it has been set as default as the screen shot shows.
   [image]
2. gk_magazine_quickstart_J!3.zip: it is installed correctly too, but there is no any additional items appeared in the template manager.
3. gk_magazine_rest_files_J!3.zip: It does not installed - *Warning JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file*

I saw similar situations with other Joomla templates and I need to know what are the rules of each file described above in the installation of the new templates? are all of them are important? or just the first file only?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Comment: @miroxlav I tired before stackExchange sites for some products such as drupal, but I found that the heavier traffic and the best response here in the stackoverflow. However, it is not bad idea.

Comment: for tag [tag:joomla] and other tags closely associated with it: if you check numbers of unanswered questions here at [SO] and on J! dedicated site, you will see the difference. Joomla site has currently very active community with great answer times. Also please instead of looking only to traffic, consider supporting of new SE spinoffs in gaining the necessary momentum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the file structure you can tell what it is!

**gk_magazine_rest_files_J!3.zip:**

[image]

This one is as the name says it 'rest files' means: `plugins`, `notes` for a module and a few `photoshop` images (*.psd)

**gk_magazine_quickstart_J!3.zip:**

[image]

This one is a Joomla Site with the `gk_magazine_J!3.zip` Template which you can find in the folder templates

**gk_magazine_J!3.zip:**

[image]

This one is a template

**EDIT:**

*Also what's Joomla Site with gk_magazine template mean too?*

It means that this is a basic Joomla site which you can copy into your server root folder (e.g. htdocs on XAMPP)

You can see the templates in the templates folder here:

[image]

beeze3, protostar and system are some Joomla standard templates which are all in a new basic Joomla site. There also beeze5 or beeze20 as an example, but these are not automatically included in the basic Joomla site

Comment: In the official documentation of Joomla, there is no any regarding for those files, they only told a file that should be uploaded and installed and hence I need to know what's `rest files` mean and how do they work? Also what's Joomla Site with gk_magazine template mean too?

Comment: @sємsєм In the rest files are just a few plugins in the plugins folder , a note for a module and a few photoshop images probably from the template. *Also what's Joomla Site with gk_magazine template mean too?* It means it's a basic Joomla site with the gk_magazine template in it!

Comment: @sємsєм updated my answer, hope it helps! Also why you don't see anything for `gk_magazine_quickstart_J!3.zip` in the template manager is because this is a Joomla site and not a template

Comment: So, the site is regarded as a customized installation of Joomla that runs it with the template, but why it accepted to be installed on the current working joomla installtion?!
About rest I can understand that it offers another extension that may be required for some features of the templates, could not it?

Comment: @sємsєм You can try to check your server root folder if the Joomla site gets installed as a site otherwise i think Joomla could think it is a component or something like that. Yes the plugins in the rest files are extensions for the template/site (Not all of them, there is also a facebook plugin).